# Launch gdb automatically on Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

Is there a way to automatically start a process under gdb on Linux? An equivalent of setting the [Image File Execution Options on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx).

I am trying to debug start-up phase of a process that is launched from another one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would normally move the real program out of the way, and replace it with a script that launches the program under GDB with the same parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec gdb -args <realprog> "$@"
```

If that doesn't work due to the output being redirected to file, or something, then try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec xterm -e gdb -args <realprog> "$@"
```

That should give you a pop-up terminal with GDB running inside.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to go through all that registry voodoo on Linux :)

Simply:

1) Rename your program

2) Write a shell script that calls gdb with your (renamed) program and passes any arguments you want. Make sure you "chmod +rx" your script.

3) Name the shell script the original name of your program, and put it in the same directory as your program

4) Execute!